# Laravel in different dev environments

Tags: php, mysql, windows, laravel, xampp

I understand programming concepts but im fairly new to frameworks.

Now, there's a big project that i just got involved with. All use Mac for the development. I have windows. xampp 
php 5.5.15
mysql ver 14.14

here's what i do:

clone the project from git
composer install(no errors returned)
migrate, seed(no errors returned)

now the weird thing is, some of the functions in this project are not working.

is there anything i need to do when working on an existing laravel project?

Thanks. any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to know which functions are not working and what errors are you seeing when you attempt to call them?

Comment: i realized its a matter of research on each error, ended up to be a problem with windows enviroment. example http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php
- money_format() is undefined in Windows, also action function in routing also seemed not recognized by windows :(